# any way to combine 2 ngram language model into 1?

Tags: n-gram, language-model

I has 2 ngram language model (`model_A` and `model_B`) now.

- they are trained based on differenct corpus, so the vocabulary is different
- they are smoothed with backoff, stored in `ARPA` format, so I have 2 `ARPA` files, `ARPA_A` and `ARPA_B`.

Now if I want to interpolate them, i.e. given any phrase ABC.

- `model_C(ABC) = 0.5 * model_A(ABC) + 0.5 * model_B(ABC)`

How can I merge `ARPA_A` and `ARPA_B` into one (`ARPA_C`)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible to combine two ngram language model. Considering that you are using open fst based Open ngram.

```
ngrammerge --use_smoothing --normalize --alpha=3 --beta=2 earnest.aa.mod earnest.ab.mod >earnest.merged.mod
```